# Java throw exception @Override

Tags: java, bluej

i'm trying to create a JFrame, add a JLabel(image) to the JFrame, however this requires me to throw IOException, wich messes up my run() in my main method.

could anyone tell me how I could throw an exception or another way how I can still use my run method to start things up?

```
public class Swing extends JFrame {

    Swing ex;
    BufferedImage c;
    ImageIcon image;

    public Swing() throws IOException {
        c = ImageIO.read(new File("poker table.jpg"));
        image = new ImageIcon(c);
        this.c = c;
        initUI();
        setTitle("MyApplication");
        setSize(1370, 770);

        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }

    public void initUI() {
        JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(c));

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Swing ex = new Swing();

                ex.setVisible(true);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Surround with a try/catch either when creating the `JLabel` or in your `run()` method.

Comment: You could simply catch the exception. Do you need it to propagate for any reason?

Comment: please, Please, **PLEASE** format your code.

Comment: how do you mean boris?

Comment: Can you see the difference between the code you posted and the formatted code now? This isn't perfect, but it's readable. Can you see that it is easy to tell which items belong to which method?

Comment: I thought i just had to put every line at 8 for coding, so how do i do that then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ["catch" the exception](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html) to keep it from leaving that method:

```
try {
   c = ImageIO.read(new File("poker table.jpg"));
} catch(IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Here the `printStackTrace()` will just print a message to the console if this exception does happen (for example, if the image file is not found). If there is no exception, the `catch` block is skipped.

Comment: Yes, I was going to, but I could not back then because I needed to wait 8 minutes to accept the answer, so I went and programmed more, no need to rush me ;)